# wordpress change user primrary role

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I change the user's primrary role and not capabilities?

I have this but its wrong. This code below only changes the capability and not primrary role. I need to add a code so it changes from current role to another, from subscriber to banned or subscriber to editor.

```
$u = new WP_User( $user_id );

// Remove role
$u->remove_role( 'Subscriber' );

// Add role
$u->add_role( 'banned' );
```

click on image link below to se snapshot
[image: Screenshot 1] 
[image: Screenshot 2]

This code adds changes to capabilities and does not alter the primrary role, I wish to change the primrary role from one to another change it.

Answer (score 0):

ust note that there is a simpler way to change the user role which is especially helpful when you do not know the current role of the user: ->set_role()

Example:

```
// Fetch the WP_User object of our user.
$u = new WP_User( 3 );

// Replace the current role with 'editor' role
$u->set_role( 'editor' );
```

Note: Remember that set_role will remove the previous roles of the user and assign the new role.

Comment: please check the main description i added 2 images

Answer (score 0):

Try `set_role`, it will remove the previous role, and assign the new one to the user

```
// Get user id.
$u = new WP_User( 1 );

// Replace role to banned
$u->set_role( 'banned' );
```

Comment: please check main description i added image ,cick it